Updating Database from DataSet with multiple tables
I have an application with an editor of multiple DataTables, that are stored in a DataSet which I load through a DataAdapter. My objective is to update the database with all the changes in all of the tables. I thought of using the same DataAdapter used to load the data with a command builder, just as if it were a single DataTable.
This is how I load the DataSet:
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 
{
    con.Open();   
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Parameters;
                 SELECT * FROM Status;
                 SELECT * FROM Commands;";

    var selectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
    DataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill =
    DataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;

    DataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Parameters");
    DataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Status");
    DataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "Commands");

    DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet);
}

After the user edits the data in the various tables an update is called, in which I use the same DataAdapter with the SELECT query used to load the data in the first place and a CommandBuilder. The problem that I have is that doing like this the command builder "detects" just the first table and create the queries for the update just for said table.
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 
{
    con.Open();

    try 
    {
        DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = con;

        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new(DataAdapter);
        DataAdapter.Update(DataSet);
    }
    catch (SqlException) 
    {
    }
}

Is there a possibility to make this work such as I intended or do I have to change the approach?

From the documentation "When handling batch SQL statements that return multiple results, the implementation of Fill and FillSchema for a .NET Framework data provider retrieves schema information for only the first result.". So no it does not work the way you hoped for. And what you trying todo sound problematic way earlier. Constantly retrieving all data from multiple tables is a problem by itself in most circumstances. So even if this has worked the way you hoped for.

Using strongly typed datasets would solve most of this I reckon, and they come with a tableadaptermanager that knows which order to call things in for saves. All youre doing right now is building a worse version of some huge intrinsic functionality MS rolled into VS years ago.. If your app is .net core you might want to think about using framework for this part though (you can use a framework app to create your DAL, and then bring it into core

@Ralf ok, thank you for the clearence, what should I change my approach to then? One DataAdapter per Table? I am not so sure to get the second part of your response, I am not constantly retrieving data from the source, I do it once when I load the app and then edit it and upload the changes.

@flackoverstow I gave it a look and I kinda like it, but there seems to be a problem with that, the source of the database is set during runtime, the user enters it once the app is executed, do you have some links to some examples perhaps?

I didn't understand when you said "the source of the database is set during runtime" - is this something microsoft/visual studio is forcing you to do, or something your customer/analyst/company/boss is forcing you to do? In the past, when I've used striongly typed sets the first tableadapter added requires you to define a  conenction string, which is then placed into projectsettings. To conenct to a different database at runtime, compared to dev time, you change the connection string in settings and all new tableadapters use it by default

@flackoverstow I'm sorry, I'll try to explain better my situation: I have multiple instances of this set of the DB, once the program launches the user must select wich one to use (kind of like SSMS), so I need to set the connection string each time the app loads. I saw that the TableAdapter class gives out the Connection property, but changing that for each one of those seems not the best use to me, also it seems not to work trying that.

Will two different databases be used at the same time?

@flackoverstow no, just one at the time, but it can be different each time.

As noted above, the connection string you give when you create your first tableadapter inside a strongly typed dataset is stored in settings, and then all the other tableadapters you create use the same connection string (out of settings) - all you have to do to have all the TAs use a different database, is alter the setting (Properties.Default.Settings.YourConnectionString = (a new connection string). There are some quirks to working with tableadapters but as far as advice goes, I would recommend you make the first query in any TA SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = @id and then...

if you want other queries, like SELECT * FROM People WHERE name = @name nand age = @age you add those as separate additional queries on the same adapter. Any query you can think of that generates the right schema, can go in a TA.. even ones that use related info like SELECT * FROM People WHERE AddressID in (SELECT Id FROM Addresses WHERE Street = @streetName). Yes, theyre old tech, but as far as exerting precise control over the query, theyre pretty good, they automatically make optimistically concurrent queries, and can be configured to automatically retrieve generated database values ..
